# Prolog natural language parser, Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated

Tags: prolog, instantiation-error, nlp

i am trying to make a prolog language parser. when i go to load my script my get the error

> ```
>  ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
>  ERROR: In:
>  ERROR:   [13] throw(error(instantiation_error,_1940))
>  ERROR:    [7] <user>
>  ERROR: 
>  ERROR: Note: some frames are missing due to last-call optimization.
>  ERROR: Re-run your program in debug mode (:- debug.) to get more detail.
> ```

my code is as follows

```
sentence(Sentence,sentence(np(Noun_Phrase),vp(Verb_Phrase))):-
  np(Sentence,Noun_Phrase,Rem),
  vp(Rem,Verb_Phrase,[]).

np([X|T],np(det(X),NP2),Rem):-
  det(X),
  np2(T,NP2,Rem).

np(Sentence,Parse,Rem):- np2(Sentence,Parse,Rem).

np(Sentence,np(NP,PP),Rem):-
  np(Sentence,NP,Rem1),
  pp(Rem1,PP,Rem).

np2([H|T],np2(noun(H)),T):- noun(H).

np2([H|T],np2(adj(H),Rest),Rem):- adj(H),np2(T,Rest,Rem).  

pp([H|T],pp(prep(H),Parse),Rem):-
  prep(H),
  np(T,Parse,Rem).

vp([H|[]],verb(H),Rem):-
  verb(H).

vp([H|Rest],vp(verb(H),RestParsed),Rem):-
  verb(H),
  pp(Rest,RestParsed).

vp([H|Rest],vp(verb(H),RestParsed),Rem):-
  verb(H),
  np(Rest,RestParsed).

det(the).
noun(cat).
noun(mat).
verb(sat).
prep(on).
adj(big).
adj(fat).
adj(comfy).
```

i have read through some of the other posts on this but im still not sure where i have gone wrong.

to check that `np` `pp` and `vp` work i am using the calls; `np([the,cat,sat,on,the,mat],O,L).` , `pp([on,the,mat],P,L).` and `vp([the,cat,sat,on,the,mat],O,L).`. one call the error `ERROR: Undefined procedure: vp/3 (DWIM could not correct goal)` appears, it is the same error for all 3 calls with the only difference being `vp/3` is either `np/3` or `pp/3`

the desired goal is to use the call `sentence(some_sentence)` and have the program output the results of `np` `pp` and `vp`.

Comment: like the error says, re-run it in debug mode, the new error will show you the line which causes the error, maybe.

Comment: There's nothing in the code you posted that would throw an instantiation error. The bug is most likely elsewhere. Possibly in the code that calls this code.

Comment: yes, this was the second thing I was going to say: you show the code but you don't show how you run it, i.e. the query, the input and the output. all must be included, otherwise answering is guesswork.